# Google sign in on localhost with Angular4

Tags: angular, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google [sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) on an Angular4 app on Ubuntu 16.04.

Running locally so that I can develop the integration I am getting `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch` because localhost is not permitted by Google as an authorised domain.

I understand that it's possible to change the /etc/hosts file to get around this.  I am entering the following:

`127.0.0.1 mysite.com`

Angular is serving on 4200 so I am then trying to visit the site at mysite.com:4200 but am getting "Invalid Host header".

What am I doing wrong please?  What should the setup be?

I've also seen the options to shorten the URL, but I can't try that quickly enough because my consent screen is being verified and I would need to add the URL to the authorised domains.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are hosting your angular project on localhost. Google need's to be able to access your website so it can redirect you back to it. You could try opening port 80 and 443 in your router so your angular project is accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thanks.  I would post code, but as I understand it this is to do with the Google api checking the domain name of the incoming request and blocking it if it is not from an authorised domain.  Other people have got around this with the hosts file so I'd like to get that working if I can as that seems like a simple solution.  I believe this solution makes the request going to the google api look as if it's come from the authorised domain name listed in the hosts file and thus it allows it.

Comment: I just googled it and it seems like you can just add localhost in the whitelist in the google console. You need to whitelist it without the port so http://localhost/

Comment: I think you used to be able to do that, but it no longer lets you :(  Thanks for looking though :)

Comment: Then I guess you need to get a public ip address.